# How to fill an array of promises faster

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Here's what I need to do,
I need to enqueue an entire youtube playlist in order, so i need to do something like this

```
const track_names = await sp.get_playlist_track_names(link);

for (let i = 0; i < track_names.length; i++){
  queue[last_index] = await yt.get_video(track_names[i]);
}
```

So as you could imagine this is waaaaay to slow, because if i try to enqueue a 100 songs playlist it doesn't start playing until i get all songs info.

Is there a faster way to do it? Or to play the first song and let the program execute the function `play_song()` while my function `get_tracks_info()` getting the remaining songs.

Comment: Voting to reopen because OP doesn't want to wait for all promises to resolve, they specifically want to do something as soon as the first promise resolves

Comment: use observer api to watch variable change, and do not await any promise.

Comment: Put a `if (i == 0) play_song()` in the loop?

Comment: How about using [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to wait for any of the songs to finish download -> and then start playing and download the rest?

Answer (score 0):

If it were the track coming from my server, I would do it with streaming.

```
const trackList = await getTheListOfYourTracks();

let curTrackIndex = -1;
```

Make an api request to get the data of current track in chunks

```
function playNextTrack() {
  if (curTrackIndex <= trackList.length - 1) {
    currentTrack = trackList[curTrackIndex + 1];
    // Make API call here
    // After finish, call this function again to play next track
    ++curTrackIndex;
    playNextTrack();
  } else {
  // Do whatever after tracklist ends
  }
}

playNextTrack();
```

Then make another api request as soon as the first track is over

This way you don't have to wait for anything and it will faster